# If a div has this two classes, hide wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a wrapper that shows an image and a star.
I want to hide the wrapper if both image and star has a class named "no". It has to be both, if just only one of them has the "no" class it has to be shown.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="#" class="image no" target="_blank"><img src="something.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" class="star no"><img src="star.png"></a>
</div>
```

Something like this:

```
if ($(".image, .no") && $(".star, .no")) {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.hasClass()` is what you looking for

```
if ($(".image").hasClass("no") && $(".star").hasClass("no")) {
 // TODO
}
```

Even simpler

```
if ($(".image,.star").is(".no")){
  // TODO 
}
```

Comment: You can put both class in one selector

Comment: @SilverSurfer Not sure about hasClass with multiple selector (not tested), but even simple is works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without jQuery:

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('.image.no').length && document.querySelectorAll('.star.no').length) { 
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery to check if class exists then why to use javascript to hide the div. Use jquery all the way.

```
if ($(".image").hasClass("no") && $(".star").hasClass("no")) {
    $('#wrapper').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkAndHide(){
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.style.display =  (wrapper.querySelector(".image.no") && wrapper.querySelector(".star.no"))? "none" : "block"
}
```

JavaScript solution